# Mathematics of Hashing with numbers and letters

Tags: c++, encryption, hash

Hashing uses a way of reading the inner data of a file and mathematically creates number and letters from it. How is a mathematical equation in C++ do this?

I'm trying to make an application using C++ and Visual Studio that reads a data file and gets a SHA-256 hash sum from it. Then applies an equation to change that into different numbers and letter, but with fewer characters. This processed number and letter would be used as a password for a 7zip or a rar file. (not sure which is better made for encryption)

This is for a migitation of internet crawlers accessing content and people who shouldn't be accessing it. I do not expect it to be able to completely lock a person out.

Also, it has to be transcodable. So it has to be able to go from the Hash to the pass, and from the pass to the hash, preferably.

If anybody can help me on this, I would be so greatly appreciative and I will give you a place in the credits page, with a link to your profile or whatever if you want :3.

If you have any other questions or info, please don't hesitate to send me message.

Picture of GUI:

[image]

Comment: If you remove bytes from hash to create a password, that's one way operation.

Comment: There should be a way I would think, if not I don't mind if it's a one way operation either, I can build on that.

Comment: Well, the shortened hash is still hash, just less secure.

Comment: calculating a SHA256 digest (32 bytes) and keeping only a partial set of them (12 bytes), base64-encoded to be your 16-char 'pwd' would work for one-way. Keep in mind every bit you peel off that hash increases the probability of coincidental collision by a power of two. whatever the maximum pwd length 7zip allows, use it. every bit counts. I used 12-bytes just as an example because it blends so nicely to 4/3 upsizing to asci. And to answer your other comment, short of *compression* of the hash (which they do very poorly since they're so short and dispersed), you can forget bi-directionality.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It seems what you need is fairly simple. (Although finding an elegant mathematical solution to this problem may be fun it's really not necessary)
SHA-256 is a 32 byte long array. The letters and numbers you see are just the hexadecimal representation of the array. Since a Hex digit requires 4 bits of data each combination of two letters or numbers (or letters and numbers) represents 1 byte. This is why you need a 64 long character string to represent a 32 byte array.

To my knowledge WinRar has a password limit of 177 characters and 7z has no limitation. Theoretically you could use your original 64 character SHA-256 representation as a password. The generated password is very strong since it has 16^64 == 2^256 combinations.

However as it happens - a shorter password but a lot stronger can be generated using Base64 encoding (Wikipedia is a good place to start). With Base64 your 32 bytes array can be represented as a 43 character long password comprised of uppercase and lowercase letters as well as 9 digits and the + and / characters. So you get 64^43 > 2^256.

You can easily convert the Base64 string back to the hash.

**As a side note:**
You should notice that since AES256 uses a 256 bit key it's actually quite useless to generate a stronger password since in that case the attacker can just attack the key and neglect the password so using the SHA-256 is really enough. But I like the fact that we can generate a 43 character long password stronger than the 64 character long one.

**And yet another side note:**
Depending on the type of characters the compressor you will use accepts as a password character you could design your own Base128 encoding and lower the number of characters to 37.

Also I would suggest using 7z as it is both fast, very capable and last but not least open source.

Comment: Actually, the Base64 password will still have 256 bits of entropy, just like the hexadecimal one, since it's derived from a 256-bit hash. Yes, 43*6 = 258 > 256, but the two extra bits will simply be zero.

Comment: @IlmariKaronen - Why you might be right but regarding the password you are actually wrong. The Base64 password is generated through a table. For that reason the resulting password is not just a different representation of the same bits. It a new bit string which is 344 bits long. So unless you attack the original hash that was used to produce it you get a much greater entropy. Your point is really valid only if you know how the password was generated in the first place.

Comment: Recognizing base64-encoded data tends to be pretty easy, especially if you have more than one sample.

Comment: @IlmariKaronen - You are right. It is easy to identify a Base64 string. But if all you have is the encrypted file then you have two options - Attack the password or attack the encryption key. If you will go with the first option you will have to deal with an entropy of 2^344 or if you know you have only 64 possible characters then with an entropy of 64^43 - both are bigger than 2^256. However if you know that the password is so big you will be better off attacking the encryption key which is 2^256. But given that you know how the password is generated - You are absolutely correct.

Answer (score 1):

You are NOT looking for a hash at all. If you want reversibility from encoded to original, you want encryption. There are duh dress of ways to encrypt something, but a very simple way is to use something like [Everpassword's AES](http://www.everpassword.com/aes-encryptor) or [Crypto.org's RC4](http://www.crypo.org/tools/eng_rc4.php), with some other password as the key. (If you really don't care, you can even use a blank key, and it'll still encode to something that looks random.) The main difference is that AES generally requires padding (ignoring CTR mode) so it produces a longer result, but RC4 has a size of exactly whatever the input is. In the above links, Bo are expanded out by base64 conversion.

I don't really understand why you want to be able to get the original password, though. I can't see a single use case for being able to give someone the password, and then to let them disscover the original phrase that generated it to satisfy their curiosity, when you only ever need the encrypted one for doing anything useful. You might as well use a few characters from a hash, because no one will care how you came up with it.

Also, hashes and ciphers don't give numbers and letters. They give 1s and 0s - numbers and letters are just a convenient way of visualizing them when we want to compare or type them, since we don't handle raw binary very easily. There are many possible representations, though.